# Getting 'Invalid email address' error using AWS JS SDK v3 SES

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am getting a 400 error from AWS, and a message of 'Invalid email address' Here's the test code I'm using:

```
const { SESClient, SendEmailCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");

void async function() {
  const client = new SESClient({ region: 'us-east-1' });

  const input = {
    "Destination": {
      "BccAddresses": [],
      "CcAddresses": [
      ],
      "ToAddresses": [
        "erik@example.com"
      ]
    },
    "Message": {
      "Body": {
        "Html": {
          "Charset": "UTF-8",
          "Data": "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href=\"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon SES Developer Guide</a>."
        },
        "Text": {
          "Charset": "UTF-8",
          "Data": "This is the message body in text format."
        }
      },
      "Subject": {
        "Charset": "UTF-8",
        "Data": "Test email"
      }
    },
    "ReplyToAddresses": [],
    "ReturnPath": "",
    "ReturnPathArn": "",
    "Source": "updates@example.io",
    "SourceArn": ""
  };
  const command = new SendEmailCommand(input);
  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response);
}();
```

The domain I am using for `source` is verified, and I can successfully send an email using V2 of the SDK - so I think this may be specific to how I'm using the V3 SDK.

Comment: What if you remove the empty arrays and ReturnPath?

Comment: @stdunbar Thank you. Removing everything except Destination, Message, and Source solved it.